A wild comedy of 3 fat black guys from 20 years ago
I rememeber a wild comedy with 3 fat black guys. This was somewhere in the late 80s or the beginning of the 90s.
I remember one scene in particularly where they were arrested, thrown into a police car and they used some wires and hooks to jack the car while the cops were in it.
I also remember they used to rap A LOT.

Seems you're referring to hip hop trio The Fat Boys (who starred in some movies in the mid-late 80s) and in this instance to Disorderlies from 1987 where they hijack a police car after getting into trouble. From an online recap:

Buffy somehow turns into MacGyver here: he gets hold of the cops’ dry cleaning (?) and pushes the top of a coat hanger under the seat so he can press down on the gas pedal, at least until the police car hits something. [...] Kool and Buffy put the police car in reverse and drive off. Backwards. Using hangers. In the back of a police car. While handcuffed.

Here's the trailer:



